# Access springboot application from repl.it

Tags: java, spring-boot, replit

https://repl.it/join/gjoybdev-nodemario

I have got the springboot application running on repl.it but I am not able to access it.
I am getting the following error

```
Hmmmm.... We Couldn't Reach Your Repl
Make sure your repl has a port open and is ready to receive HTTP traffic.
```

After going through  [Deploy server repl.it](https://docs.repl.it/repls/http-servers)
I thought below changes in application.properties

```
server.address=0.0.0.0
server.port=8080
```

It gives error. My build is sucessfull

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9001; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
jdk.internal.agent.AgentConfigurationError: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9001; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:491)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:447)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:599)
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9001; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:335)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:243)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:412)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:234)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:220)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:180)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.SingleEntryRegistry.<init>(SingleEntryRegistry.java:49)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:836)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:479)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:395)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:149)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(TCPDirectSocketFactory.java:45)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:670)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:324)
```

Comment: Error says port is in use. Try another one